# Extracted solution dilemma

Tags: farm-solution

I have extracted a solution created by a third party Dev House. When I open it in VS all I get is a page of HEX. Is this right or is it somehow protected? Thanks

Powershell used to extract...

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$file = $farm.Solutions.Item("soultionName.wsp").SolutionFile
$file.SaveAs("c:\temp\solutionName.wsp")
```

Comment: Just curious...did you try renaming it to "solutionName.cab" and opening the file that way?

Comment: Die you only tried to "open" or die you "import" it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can open a WSP in Visual Studio.

You can rename the file with a .cab extension and open it write from Windows Explorer.  You'll see a few XML files (Manifest, Feature, Elements, etc.) along with the package's payload (assemblies, webpart definitions, user controls, etc.).

Comment: Sure you can import a wsp package into vs.

Comment: Right, you can IMPORT a WSP using a SharePoint project template, but you can't OPEN a WSP...two very different things.  And I'm not sure what value you'd get out of importing a WSP from a 3rd party dev house into VS.

Comment: Rob, I have changed it to .cab and like you said can view the contents. How do you import the .sln in order to edit? I'm guessing you need the full project to do this? Thanks

Comment: The WSP is just a compiled version of the project that SharePoint understands.  You would definitely need the original VS project code in order to open it in Visual Studio.  You could potentially reflect any assemblies contained in the package and try to reconstruct the source if no source is available to you.